# Topological Equivalence between $(- \pi/2, \pi/2)$ to $R$

Tags: general-topology

I know that the key is to use $\tan$ and $\arctan$ to do it. Take any $(a,b) \subset \mathbb{R}$, $(a,b)$ is open. Now I want to show $\tan^{-1}(a,b)$ is open. I need a hint for the next step (just a hint suffices) Thanks.

Comment: Well once I wrote the question I was thinking the tangent and arctan function are inverses and the arctan should map an open interval into an open interval since they are continuous.

Comment: It's not clear what you're allowed to take on faith for solving this exercise. Proving that $\tan$ and $\arctan$ are continuous from scratch won't be simple. I imagine your book expects you to just quote this fact from a real analysis/calculus course you've previously taken.

Comment: @jsk to prove that $f^{-1}(O)$ is an open in $\mathbb{R}$, whit $O$ is an open in $\mathbb{R}$, you should notice that $f^{-1}$ ought to be continous. then prove that $f^{-1}(O)$ is included in an open set in $\mathbb{R}$. Since we are dealing whit a real valued function here.

Comment: @countinghaus yes I was thinking about the continuity of $\tan$ and $arctan$ too. I think I will take it as granted they are continuous since I have never actually proved the continuity of trigonometric functions before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [definition of continuous function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Continuous_functions_between_topological_spaces) in terms of open sets.

Comment: The topological equivalence follows directly from the continuity of $\tan$ and $\arctan$? (well I think so...)

Comment: @jsk, well, you have to note that they are bijective on that interval. Then it is an homeomorphism since tan is continuous and arctan is also continuous (both are differentiable, hence continuous)